# How to create datastore for REST webservice using OAuth 2.0 in SAP BODS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, webservice-client, sap-data-services

I am trying to create a datastore in SAP BODS using authorization schema as OAuth 2.0. for webservice type REST.

I have client ID, client secret, endpoint URL, what are the field's will be required as mandatory to connect successfully.

Kindly suggest stepwise process to do so.

[image]

i have tried by adding these details.

but getting the below error:

[image]